# Third Party JS file messing up with my CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

To generate menu, my current application is using coolmenu4, third party api.

Issue is when ever user is putting mouse over the menu element, it is setting visibility of some select box as hidden.

Is there any way I can stop this third party libraries from chaning my css.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the third party api so that your css would work, or you can change the selector of your menu in order for the third party api not to override your defined css. Hope it would help!